# .match() with a regular expression returns null

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to do something I thought would be pretty easy to do, which is to restrict a string to certain characters by matching a regular expression.

```
var value = 'FailureStr1ng';
var type = 'ALPHA';
var regex = null;

switch(type) {
    case 'ALPHA':
        regex = '^[a-zA-Z]+$';
        break;
    case 'NUMERIC':
        regex = '^[0-9]+$';
        break;
    case 'ALPHANUMERIC':
        regex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$';
        break;
}

return value.match(regex);
```

For some reason, when using the match it always returns `null`. Is there a way to fix this, or a better method to do this?

**Note:** The code here is a snippet of much larger code, and in turn the value and type variable are usually defined by another method.

Comment: It returns null because you have a `1` in the string so it does not match.  Changing it to a valid string returns that string.  http://jsfiddle.net/GLVAj/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You want `RegExp.test`, which tests a value for a match instead of retrieving the match. With your existing code, that would mean:

```
if(!new RegExp(regex).test(value)){
    alert('Your string was invalid.');
}
```

However, it would be preferable to use RegExp literals instead of strings, as they're much more efficient and clear, and less prone to error:

```
var value = 'FailureStr1ng';
var type = 'ALPHA';
var regex = null;

switch(type) {
    case 'ALPHA':
        regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        break;
    case 'NUMERIC':
        regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
        break;
    case 'ALPHANUMERIC':
        regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
        break;
}

if(!regex.test(value)) {
    alert('Your string was invalid.');
}
```

Even better, use a dictionary:

```
var expressions = {
    ALPHA: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
    NUMERIC: /^[0-9]+$/,
    ALPHANUMERIC: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
};

if(!expressions[type].test(value)) {
    alert('Your string was invalid.');
}
```

Comment: I was putting the regex pattern inside single quotes and that was my issue... :D)

Answer (score 18):

Regex must be surrounded with `/`, not `'`, so that JavaScript creates a variable of type regex, not of type string. So for instance, for your ALPHA case, you should have

```
regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

See [MDN's page on `.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for more information about using `.match`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it's inside a `function { ... }`. Are you `return`ing anything? If not, that's why you're getting `null` back...

Also, regexes are surrounded by slashes (`/.../`), not quotes.

Comment: I have fixed the code up now, I meant that value.match(regex) was returning null. Not the function.

Comment: The value returned from a function that doesn't return anything is `undefined`, not `null`.