# how to check in javascript if is string in 100 000,00 format

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, format, match

let's say I have a string contained numbers,
and I need to check if it's in specific format where would be every thousand separated by a space, followed by "," and 2 digits with decimals.

So for example, 20125,33 would be like 20 125,33
                122000111,15 would be like 122 000 111,15.
I tried this:

```
element(by.id('OTB')).getText()
        .then(function(text){
          var reg = new RegExp("[0-9]{1,3}\s[0-9]{3},[0-9]{2}$","g");
          expect(text.match(reg)).toBe(true);
```

But I'm still getting "Expected null to be true"
I will be glad for any help

Comment: Are you 100% certain that your `text` contains a string that matches that regular expression?

Comment: Hi, yes, I am, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the method `test` on the regex, not `match` on the string.

```
expect(reg.test(text)).toBe(true);
```

[.match() with a regular expression returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663812/match-with-a-regular-expression-returns-null)

Comment: Hi, thank you! It seems to be working. 
And what if I would have in that string in the end also a USD?

Comment: Really thank you for that test() :))) 

For future askers about regular expressions: 
This was really helpful too: [link] (www.regexr.com) 

And in the end I used this: 

`element(by.id('OTB')).getText()`
       `.then(function(text){`
         `var reg = /([0-9]{1,3})((\s)([0-9]{3}))*,([0-9]{2})(\s)(any text)/g;`

      `expect(reg.test(text)).toBe(true);`
       `});`

-- I'm sorry for such a bad text format, I just can't make it better